# Customize Jquery validation message css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

How can i customize the Jquery validation message in css

From this 
[image]

To this:
[image]

Can i anyone help me produce the above styling?

I tried  `label.error {
    float: none;
    padding-left: .5em;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-opacity: .90;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    opacity: .90;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}`

But i couldn't align it correctly [image]

Thanks

Comment: What have your tried so far?... and did you make this yourself or is this a plugin you're using?

Comment: i am using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation and i tried float: none;
 padding-left: .5em;
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: #333;
 font-size: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 color: #FFF;
 display: none;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;

Comment: -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 -moz-opacity: .90;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
 opacity: .90;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-top: -2px; but i couldn't align it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
box {
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult to customize the default error message like that.

Its better you can do custom validation for this. ie instead of showing the default error message you can show a message popup. So according to the type of error you can show the corresponding popup.

A similar thing can be seen in this http://www.underdog.co.uk/